# Problem deleting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, constraints

When I do something like:

> DELETE FROM users_has_pais WHERE users_id = 151

I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gisele`.`users_has_pais`, CONSTRAINT `users_has_pais_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I'm not sure what the problem is, though I'm guessing it has something to do with the ON DELETE NO ACTION. I don't know what I should change that to though... for reference I've pasted a dump of my tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
`url` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`responsable` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`role` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`fecha` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=162 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pais` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pais` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `pais` (`pais`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

users_has_pais | CREATE TABLE `users_has_pais` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`users_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pais_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `user` (`users_id`),
KEY `index3` (`pais_id`),
KEY `users_id` (`users_id`),
KEY `pais_id` (`pais_id`),
CONSTRAINT `users_has_pais_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `users_has_pais_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pais_id`) REFERENCES `pais` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

EDIT: 
[pastie of the constraint information](http://pastie.org/2079162)

Comment: can you find and post the definition for the constraint "users_has_pais_ibfk_3"?

Comment: @mtazva I've copied the information related to the constraint in the pastie link I left in the post thread.. NOt sure if that's what you requested me for though

Comment: constraint appears to be defined correctly - it was just a hunch (same as @Adrian). Sorry, that was my only clue. I'll come back if anything else hits me.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to delete a record that's referenced by a constraint in another table. Thus, you need to do one of the following:

- Change constraint to cascade delete (or another constraint rule), if that makes sense in your logic
- Warn user of the issue and advise him to delete the other object first
- Make your application delete the dependent rows and then the row you are trying to delete (as per @RacerX comment).

**Update**

After viewing your data structure with more details, I suspect that your constraint may be defined backwards. Can you post the constraint definition?

Comment: I prefer to have the application delete the dependant FK rows first, then delete the row in question.  Cascade deletes are nice, but they eliminate one safeguard that FKs provide.  If the application is out of control (buggy) designing it with lots of cascade delete can be a problem.

Comment: I know. That's why I gave OP options. OP has to know what he can do. Also, there are such things as buggy FKs as well (wrongly defined ones)

Answer (score 0):

My SQL knowledge isn't exactly top notch, but it looks like you're deleting something thats being referenced as a foreign key.

Comment: You don't "work around it".  It's an integrity rule defined in the database, and you have to abide by it.  That means either you delete everything (I mean, all rows involved), or you delete nothing at all.  If you "delete everything", then it's up to you to decide whether you do this by cascaded deletes, application-controlled deletes, a delete trigger on the table, or by putting the whole operation in a stored procedure.  The dangers of cascaded deletes have been pointed out by RacerX in his remark.